# How to add an accepted but not published paper to my CV?

Tags: publications, arxiv

My first paper has been accepted to a CS conference, *it went through a double blind peer-reviewed* process. Soon it will appear in conference proceedings from Springer.

How to add it to my CV? Also, should I make an arxiv print available ?

Comment: Addressing the sub-question that is not answered in 
AnonymousPhysicist's linked question: The fact that it's double-blind is not relevant any longer for anything as soon as the paper accepted. You can tell the whole world about your paper.

Comment: "How to add accepted paper to CV" and "should I make an arxiv print available for my accepted paper" are two separate questions. Flagged this question as too broad.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I am looking for words that I should put in my CV, "accepted", "soon to be published"  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following entry in your publication list (with the correct titles etcetera swapped in, or course):

A. Mitoz: The essence of mathematics lies in an Painlevé property group. In: Proceedings of the International Conference of Computer Science 2021, to appear.

Comment: Yes. Or `(forthcoming)` or `(in print)` etc.